# Entity Framework new table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I updated the project from Entity Framework 5 to 6 and when I start my project a new table is created in the db: `dbo.__MigrationHistory`. I am using code first and I will guess this is to keep track to the history right?

This was not created there in EF 5.

How can I prevent this table to be created?

Answer (score 0):

when automatic updates run against a database they should apply all changes they can find. There is a system table on the database called migration history that helps with this.
you can manipulate Migration Table but I don't sure that you can disable of creating it.
see this link http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Migrations%20History%20Table%20Customization

Comment: This table was not there before (EF5) after I migrated today to EF6 and started the project, the table just show up ... same code not changes in the solution ...

Answer (score 0):

one of Entity framework specification is  **Idempotent migrations scripts**

it's obvious that package manager Already  Enabled-Migration 
so you have to disable it using

```
 AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
```

then set your Initializer

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContextType>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists());
```

Answer (score 0):

> In Entity Framework 5 this table was a system table if the application
>   used Microsoft Sql Server database. This has changed in Entity
>   Framework 6

Code First needs the Migration History table so you can't remove it, but you can customise it

Reference: [Customizing the Migrations History Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456841.aspx)